# Combining org-protocol with org-roam

Tags: org-roam, org-protocol

Hi everybody roamy :),

I am attempting to combine org-protocol with org-roam.
My chrome bookmark contains: `javascript:location.href = 'org-protocol://roam-ref?template=p&ref=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title).`

Does anybody has a nice template where I could include the selected text too?

Also, I would like the frame to pop up or at least be brought to the front (at the moment, the creation of the capturing happens in the background, so I have to move to Emacs to finish the capture).
Thanks so much for you input!

Answer (score 0):

Two steps in my case:

1. You use add `&body..` to the bookmarklet, this is from the current documentation of org-roam:

```
javascript:location.href = 'org-protocol://roam-ref?template=r&ref='
          + encodeURIComponent(location.href)
          + '&title='
          + encodeURIComponent(document.title)
          + '&body='
          + encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

2. Change the capture template to include the body, in my case I added `\n\n${body}`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-roam-capture-ref-templates
   '(("r" "ref" plain "%?" :target
      (file+head "${slug}.org" "#+title: ${title}\n\n${body}")
      :unnarrowed t))))
```